# After adding bootstrap to site, column divs disappeared

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I ended up having to add Bootstrap to my website after I thought I finished coding it. After adding the grid to the respective spans the columns disappear. If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <a href="intro.html"><span align="center">
                    <h1 style="position:relative;bottom:15px">Introduction</h1>
                </span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <a href="business.html"><span align="center">
                    <h1 style="position:relative;bottom:30px">Analyzing a Business</h1>
                </span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <a href="financialratios.html"><span align="center">
                    <h1 style="position:relative;bottom:-40px">Financial Ratios</h1>
                </span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <a href="valuation.html"><span align="center">
                    <h1 style="position:relative;bottom:-25px">Valuation</h1>
                </span></a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Keep in mind that before adding the container, rows, and columns the spans appeared normally.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you are defining your columns, you are specifying the layout for the smallest grid breakpoint (<576px). This could be causing the issue if you are viewing your site on desktop. Refer to this table for the proper syntax for defining your Bootstrap grids, which can also be found in the Bootstrap documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).
[image]